# Which manga was being parodied in episode 5 of Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei?

Tags: sayonara-zetsubou-sensei

In episode 5 of *Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei*, I think the following scenes might parody some manga. What I want to know is which manga the author intended to parody.

[image: 18:25 of episode 5]

Comment: At the very least make sure the spelling in your Title is correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is clearly a reference to the manga [Black Jack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Jack_(manga)) by Tezuka Osamu. The doctor is referred to as "A detoxified Dr. BJ" in a previous screenshot:

[image]

The joke probably only makes sense if you know a bit about Black Jack, so here's [MAL's summary](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1520/Black_Jack) of the series (based on the anime entry). Note that it would sound far less interesting if he were an ordinary doctor.

> In the medical profession, there is a name spoken in hushed tones, of an unlicensed genius physician who can save lives—for a price. His name is Black Jack, and he is a dashing, moody figure, caped in black, a Harlock of medicine, a man who lives by no rules other than his own—and the Hippocratic Oath. A man who would defy the will of God himself in the name of preserving life.

Anime News Network's [trivia list](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=7767&page=22) for the show agrees that this is the reference being made:

> In **episode 5**, Dr BJ is obviously refers to Black Jack, from the anime/manga of the same name.

Comment: Just so you know, ANN's trivia list is not official in any way. So it is further evidence that you aren't the only one thinking this, but I wouldn't say it really "confirms" anything.

Comment: @atlantiza I'm well aware that ANN's triva list isn't official. I included it mainly because it's a useful place to check for these sorts of references. As with most references, there's almost certainly no official confirmation of this by any of the producers.

Comment: I've changed that sentence so that the active verb is "agree" rather than "confirm" since the latter could be interpreted to give undue weight to the source.

Comment: Right, I agree that it's useful but by no means does it confirm anything :)